# Parametric port declaration in SystemVerilog

Tags: templates, hardware, system-verilog

I am trying to develop a module that can have one of two interfaces as ports. The behavior of the module change very little depending on which of the two interfaces is used therefore I would like to implement it as a single module.

```
module m(
    input logic clock,
    input logic reset,

`ifdef IF1
    if1.receiver link
`else
    if2.receiver link
`endif
...
);
```

The code above works fine but I would like to make the choice parametric as I might want to instantiate different version of this module in a design.

Something like this:

```
module m #(parameter IF = 0)(
    input logic clock,
    input logic reset,

generate
    if (IF1)
        if1.receiver link
    else
        if2.receiver link
endgenerate
...
);
```

Now this second example does not work BUT can this be achieved in system-verilog? I can't find a definitive answer in the language specification.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the second example **does not work**. xvlog tells me "keyword generate used in incorrect context". What I would like to know is whether this can be achieved in other ways.

Comment: I quickly scanned the standard formal syntax and I can't find anything relating to 'generate' in the header, port declaration, parameter or ports section. Generate only appears in the module items section.

Comment: ok so what I tried is definitely not correct? Regardless, can this be correctly implemented in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic `interface` port instead of specifying `if1` or `if2`. Then you can connect any kind of interface to that port as long as all the references to names are valid for all kinds. So in your example, both interfaces need a receiver modport.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am not sure what you mean with generic `interface` port.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/bradpierce.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/generic-sv-programming-with-generic-interface-ports/amp/

Comment: @dave_59 Thank you. I have always wanted to look more closely at interfaces. Great example.